# Get value of row as an array on click of first column

Tags: html, html-table

I have a html table with n number of rows. The first column of each row is a radio button . I want to achieve the following functionality :

When a user clicks on the radio button (first column) , I want to get corresponding row values as an array.

Thank you

Comment: you can get the data using jquery functions

Comment: What have you tried so far?  add some HTML code at least in the question, if you need more help

Comment: I don't know this method is right or not but I am able to achieve what I want.

$("#table_id tbody").on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function (e) {
      // all td value with comma seprated
         var tdValue = $(this).children().closest("tr").children('td').map(function (index, val) {
            return $(this).text();
        }).toArray();
});

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this..

```
$("#table_id tbody").on('click', 'tr td:first-child', function (e) {
    var data = [];
    $(this).parent('tr').find('td:not(:first)').map(function(index, val) {
        data.push($(val).html());
    }));
});
```

Comment: Note: here i used bind for the first td of the tr, not the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

For example
HTML code :

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="check" type="radio" class="radiobtn" /></td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 2</td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="check" type="radio" class="radiobtn" /></td>
        <td>Data 5</td>
        <td>Data 6</td>
        <td>Data 7</td>
        <td>Data 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="check" type="radio" class="radiobtn" /></td>
        <td>Data 9</td>
        <td>Data 10</td>
        <td>Data 11</td>
        <td>Data 12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="check" type="radio" class="radiobtn" /></td>
        <td>Data 13</td>
        <td>Data 14</td>
        <td>Data 15</td>
        <td>Data 16</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript (jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".radiobtn").click(function(){
        var tds = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
  console.log(tds);
        var dataArray =[];
        for(i=1;i < tds.length;i++) 
            dataArray.push($(tds[i]).html());
        //Use dataArray here
       $("#console").html(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
    });
});
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/ivoglent/pen/rejyxb